# Question is not mine but it is shown to be asked by me

Tags: support, specific-question

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962341/loading-a-map-by-lat-and-lang-stored-in-a-database) appears to be asked by me, but it is not mine. I never asked this. I just provided an answer to the question. I am really surprised how this question is appearing in the list of questions asked by me. Any Idea?

Comment: Prob the result of an account merge at some point. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Account merge? I have no idea about this.

Comment: Well that looks like what happened. If you're not aware of it, might very well be a mixup. Wait for a moderator to answer, or use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page and explain the situation.

Comment: @AsmatAli Just sounds like you're _playing possum_ here, while looking suspicious.

Comment: Happen to know Mohammad Talha? http://web.archive.org/web/20150515074124/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962341/loading-a-map-by-lat-and-lang-stored-in-a-database

Comment: Yeah, @GertArnold, that was the actual question. So I am going to assume that at some point this guy logged in from the same computer from where I used to login. This can happen in institutional labs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it was an automatic merge and the only time a merge is automatic is when both accounts have the same e-mail.

Tim Post left this comment on an answer of mine over on MSE (my emphasis):

> We wouldn't merge them if there's no activity between the two unless **you accidentally associate an email known to both accounts with both accounts**, at which point the system would automatically merge them....

[Does the integration of Jobs and CVs threaten anonymity as a feature of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271586/does-the-integration-of-jobs-and-cvs-threaten-anonymity-as-a-feature-of-stack-ex/271587#comment881352_271587)

So, if it wasn't you who created the other account the only thing I can think of is that someone accidentally used your e-mail when creating/updating their account which triggered the merge, which (to be honest) is highly unlikely as they would need access to that e-mail to register the account.

Only someone with more access to the data will be able to shed more light on this.

Comment: Ah, Good answer. The previous one which just got deleted was too offensive.. :)

Comment: note that asker would have to register their account (SO requires this to ask question) and because of that, they would have to also have access to account's email

Comment: @gnat - good point.

Comment: @gnat - wouldn't that mean that the second account was a sock puppet?

Comment: @AsmatAli I can't spot anything _offensive_ from the deleted answer, it probably just told the truth!.

Comment: @AsmatAli given facts in evidence at the time written, my answer was the most likely explanation.  However, since it was not a manual merge  (as ChrisF pointed out), it eliminated a strong part of my argument, so I deleted it to give you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, You yourself put offensive comments.